# Do the Publication Retraction impact on Co-authors

Tags: withdraw, retraction

I am a co-author of a retracted paper. It is very unfortunate for me. I just provided technical assistance in the experiment but the 1st author did some scientific misconduct and as a result, the article has been withdrawn by the corresponding author. I want to know how it is going to impact my career. I just helped with the experiment designing and completely unaware of the scientific misconduct by the 1st author and now I am suffering. Please suggest what to do. I want to stay in the same field of research. Hence, is it possible that my abilities will be judged by this retracted article?

Comment: " I want to know how it is going to impact my career": What point of your career are you in?

Comment: I am a PhD student now. I want to know that is it going to hamper my early research career? Eg: Post-doctoral application, early career research grants etc.

Comment: I am a senior Ph.D. student and my future area of research will remain the same. Is the retracted co-authored article going to affect my future application for postdoctoral positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that this will affect you unless you have a way to clearly distance yourself from the misconduct. Of course, if the retraction, etc. isn't especially public then it is possible no one will notice.

Being a student now is both a hinderance and a help. Since you are at the very beginning of your career you can likely validly claim that you were blindsided by superiors, being a bit naive yourself. You aren't expected to be as sophisticated as a professor would be.

On the other hand, I suspect that it is only in seeking your first position that you would need to deal seriously with it. Once you have your own position you are building your own reputation. But you will, likely, be questioned on it and need a good, complete, and valid response. But I suspect that if it is reasonable, then it would be accepted by most people/places.